# Change level of appendix in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I would like to have the title of my appendix as a part level in my table of content.
For the moment I have this :
[image]

I would like to have Annexes as part level. Now it's like a chapter.

In my latex code I have :

```
\usepackage[toc,page,title,titletoc,header]{appendix} % pour les annexes
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexes} % indique le nom de la table des annexes dans la toc

\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Annexes} % Nom du titre de la page des annexes
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}}
```

I include my annexe.tex file like this : `\include{annexe}`

And the beginning of the annexe.tex file looks like this :
[image]

....

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome on TeX.Sx.

Comment: Why uses the the appendix paxkzge and environment if the appendices are chapters ? The switch `\appendix` in standard classes would be sufficient. And if you want a part `Annexes` in the toc  why not declare it as `\part{Annexes}` either in the main just before the inlude, or inside it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using memoir!

When using memoir, parts and chapters look alike in the toc, so it is unclear for me what you really want!

Still, you may try to add the following to the preamble of your document and check if you get the desired output.

```latex
\renewcommand{\addappheadtotoc}{%
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\appendixtocname}}
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm using memoir! but your solution worked !
Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @Florent Why don't you know if you are using `memoir`? Do you look at your code? You are using memoir if you have `\documentclass{memoir}` . If you have, say, `\documentclass{something}` then you are using the `something` class. ---GOM

Comment: @Peter Wilson, I believe Florent's document is an academic dissertation, so most probably there is base template, and it is possible that this template is provided as a class itself, hiding the real class behind.

Comment: @JoãoLourenço If that is the case then we have no idea of the basis of the code for the document nor what the "template" provides or changes.

Comment: @Peter Wilson, you are right. That’s why I said “I am assuming that you are using memoir”. However, my assumption was not totally unfounded, as in the beginning of the “annexe.tex” file there is a reference to “\counterwithin{…}” which is defined in memoir. :)

Comment: @JoãoLourenço  Since 2018 `\counterwithin` and friends are defined in the LaTeX kernel so using `\counterwithin` does not mean that the `memoir` class is being used, it could be any class.